# pointer to integer type modeled on pointer to typedef type

Tags: c, pointers, typedef

For didactic motives, i want to build a pointer to an integer, and i take a model from a pointer to a typedef (working example below in (1) ) but the example at (0) gives the mesage   "error: syntax error before '=' token" at   ptr =&a;      and i can not understand why. I will thank the correction.The code is:

(0)  //failing code

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int  *ptr;

int main(){
int a;
ptr =&a;      //<-----"error: syntax error before '=' token"
a =2;
printf("%d\an",a);
return 0;
}
```

(1)  //working code

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct sum {
int a,b,c;
} mytype;

int main(){

mytype  sum_operation;    
mytype *ptr;

ptr = &sum_operation;

(*ptr).a = 1;
(*ptr).b = 3;       

(*ptr).c =(*ptr).b + (*ptr).a  ;
printf("%d\n",(*ptr).c);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't indent your paragraphs. You ended up code-formatting non-code.

Comment: What do you expect `ptr =&a;` to do?

Answer (score 4):

This syntax:

```
typedef int  *ptr;
```

Is not a pointer to a typedef. You're defining a new type named `ptr` which is a pointer to an integer.

This syntax:

```
ptr = &a;
```

is equivalent to:

```
int* = &a; // error: syntax error before '=' token
```

Which is incorrect as you must specify a variable name:

```
ptr myPointer = &a
```

which is equivalent to:

```
int* myPointer = &a;
```

Comment: I just want to get the number '2' printed using the type declared in  "typedef int  *ptr;"  above, as in the working code the sum of 3 and 1 is got using the 'mytype' type declared.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare a variable, you need to give it a name:

```
ptr b = &a;
//  ^ This part.
```

Comment: The OP doesn't know the meaning of `typedef int  *ptr` he's thinking it a (pointer to a typedef).

Comment: @rullof: You think he's expecting the `typedef` line to declare a variable named `ptr`? Perhaps. I'm not really sure what he's thinking.

Comment: @rullof: I interpreted the reference to "pointer to a typedef" as referring to the pointer declared in the second code snippet, which is a pointer to a typedef'd type. Under that interpretation, the mistake is merely calling it "pointer to a typedef" rather than "pointer to a struct" or "pointer to a typedef'd type". It's possible that the OP might not know how to declare structs without typedef, and that he's conflated the two concepts.

Comment: I just want to get the number '2' printed using the type declared in  "typedef int  *ptr;"  above, as in the working code the sum of 3 and 1 is got using the 'mytype' type declared.